# Display Image in fixed size div

Tags: javascript, image, html

I've a 100*100 `<div>` in which I would like to display images of different sizes randomly without stretching them.

Note:The image should appear as origional, just resizing should be done inorder to place it in box

Comment: This question makes no sense. How can it appear as original when it's to be shrunk to fit into the box? Can you make examples of what happens to an image less than, and one more than 100 pixels wide?

Comment: I think he means maintaining the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this style will help you:

```
div {
   position:relative;
}

div img {
   max-width:100%;max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: beacuse i've set max-width,max-height to percentage, more you can read there: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple function to calculate your aspect ratio and size the image down. it takes the path to the file and the original width and height of the image. you can provide all that however you see fit. `'myElement'` would be the id of your image element.

```
function loadImage(filename, width, height) {

    var aspect = width / height;
    var w, h;

    if (width > height) {
        w = 100;
        h = Math.round(100 / aspect);
    }
    else {
        h = 100;
        w = Math.round(100 * aspect);
    }

    var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
    element.src = filename;
    element.style.width = w + 'px';
    element.style.height = h + 'px';
}
```